# Reshape Count Data using R

Tags: r

I currently have a data set that lists frequencies for each unique ID. I would like to convert the data so that each row is its own observation. This requires combining columns and creating factors as well as expanding the rows. Below is and example of how the data currently looks.

```
Developer   Total     Attached    Detached     New   Old 
Dev A       2         1           1            0     2
Dev B       3         2           1            2     1
```

Where total is the "count.  attached/detached are related an New/Old are related.

I would like to convert this to the following:

```
Developer      Type              Age
Developer A   Attached      Old
Developer A   Detached     Old
Developer B   Attached      New
Developer B   Attached      New
Developer B   Detached     Old
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: how exactly do you know for developer B that the 2x attached goes to 2x new, and the 1x detached goes to 1x old?

Comment: @erocoar - really good point. There isn't enough information here to guess what should be assigned to what for `Dev B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [erocoar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245541/reshape-count-data-using-r#comment85495122_49245541) and [thelatemail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245541/reshape-count-data-using-r#comment85495168_49245541), there is an ambiguity in the results without additional information. However, the OP has shown the expected result. From this, we can derive an additional rule: "Treat `Type` and `Age` independently and fill up in column order".

The solutions below try to reproduce the expected result by a series of reshaping operations. For reshaping, the `melt()` and `dcast()` functions from the `data.table` package are used. There are two variants.

#### 1. Reshape in one go

```
library(data.table)
# reshape from wide to long
long <- melt(setDT(DT), id.vars = c("Developer", "Total"))
# create new variable var
long[variable %like% "tached", var2 := "Type"][
  variable %in% c("New", "Old"), var2 := "Age"][
    , var2 := forcats::fct_inorder(var2)][]
```

> ```
>    Developer Total variable value var2
> 1:     Dev A     2 Attached     1 Type
> 2:     Dev B     3 Attached     2 Type
> 3:     Dev A     2 Detached     1 Type
> 4:     Dev B     3 Detached     1 Type
> 5:     Dev A     2      New     0  Age
> 6:     Dev B     3      New     2  Age
> 7:     Dev A     2      Old     2  Age
> 8:     Dev B     3      Old     1  Age
> ```

```
# repeat row indices as many times as given by value
repeated_rows <- long[rep(1:.N, value)]
repeated_rows
```

> ```
>     Developer Total variable value var2
>  1:     Dev A     2 Attached     1 Type
>  2:     Dev B     3 Attached     2 Type
>  3:     Dev B     3 Attached     2 Type
>  4:     Dev A     2 Detached     1 Type
>  5:     Dev B     3 Detached     1 Type
>  6:     Dev B     3      New     2  Age
>  7:     Dev B     3      New     2  Age
>  8:     Dev A     2      Old     2  Age
>  9:     Dev A     2      Old     2  Age
> 10:     Dev B     3      Old     1  Age
> ```

```
# partial reshape from long to wide
result <- dcast(repeated_rows, Developer + rowid(var2, Developer) ~ var2, 
                value.var = "variable")[
  # remove helper column
  , var2 := NULL][]
result
```

> ```
>    Developer     Type Age
> 1:     Dev A Attached Old
> 2:     Dev A Detached Old
> 3:     Dev B Attached New
> 4:     Dev B Attached New
> 5:     Dev B Detached Old
> ```

#### 2. Reshape `Type` and `Age` columns separately

```
library(data.table)
result <- merge(
  melt(setDT(DT), measure.vars = patterns("tached"),
       variable.name = c("Type"))[
         rep(1:.N, value), .(Developer, rn = rowid(Developer), Type)],
  melt(setDT(DT), measure.vars = patterns("New|Old"),
       variable.name = c("Age"))[
         rep(1:.N, value), .(Developer, rn = rowid(Developer), Age)]
)[, rn := NULL][]
result
```

> ```
>    Developer     Type Age
> 1:     Dev A Attached Old
> 2:     Dev A Detached Old
> 3:     Dev B Attached New
> 4:     Dev B Attached New
> 5:     Dev B Detached Old
> ```

#### Verify result

```
merge(
  dcast(result, Developer ~ Type), 
  dcast(result, Developer ~ Age), 
  by = "Developer")
```

> ```
>    Developer Attached Detached New Old
> 1:     Dev A        1        1   0   2
> 2:     Dev B        2        1   2   1
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
  'Developer   Total     Attached    Detached     New   Old 
"Dev A"       2         1           1            0     2
"Dev B"       3         2           1            2     1',
  colClasses = list(integer = 2:6))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking so much time to answer my question as well as understanding what I was asking! This exactly what I needed to get done.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are probably much cleaner ways to do it (maybe plyr but I'm not very familiar with it) you can do a split on your original data and then loop over the resulting list.
This is what it would look like (data is a data.frame of your original data):

```
devList = split(x = data, f = data$developer)
newData = data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(devList), ncol = 6,data = 0))
colnames(newData) = c("developer", "total", "attached", "detached", "new", "old")

for(i in 1:length(devList)) {
  item = devList[[i]]
  newData$developer[i] = as.character(item$developer[i])
  newData$total[i] = nrow(item)
  for (b in 1:nrow(item)) {
    if(item$type[b] == 1) {
      newData$attached[i] = newData$attached[i] + 1
    } else {
      newData$detached[i] = newData$detached[i] + 1
    }
    if(item$age[b] == 1) {
      newData$new[i] = newData$new[i] + 1
    } else {
      newData$old[i] = newData$old[i] + 1
    }  
  }
}
```

Edit: My answer was posted before the OP changed the integers (for attached/detached and new/old) to strings. I suspect that the original data did not change. Therefore I keep my answer as it is for the moment.